# & on left of function (regarding c++ syntax)

Tags: c++, syntax

My question is simple.  I have a function that needs to be implemented in a .cpp file.

Prototype:

```
const Location &getTop(void) const;
```

That is in the header.

When I try to stub it out for my .cpp file I make it this:

```
const Location LocationStack::&getTop(void) const{

}
```

I get the error: '&' : illegal token on right side of '::'  How do I fix this?  I know the syntax is definitely wrong.

Comment: This is legacy from the folks who prefer putting `*` and `&` next to variable names instead of type names, e.g. `const char *a;` instead of `const char* a;`. And that's legacy from C syntax rules.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: C++ has the same syntax rules as C in this area. The difference is cultural (mostly, I think, because Stroustrup prefers to put the `*` next to the variable name).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Also to maintain compatibility with existing C code. And maybe also because the first C++ implementation (cfront) output C.

Comment: @klamse: BTW, `*` is a *legal* token on the right side of `::`. Not useful in this case, but for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
const Location &getTop(void) const;
```

declares a function which returns a `const` reference to `Location`. It would be less confusing with the following formatting:

```
const Location& getTop(void) const;
```

To fix the compilation error, try

```
const Location& LocationStack::getTop(void) const
```

Comment: This fixed the compiler error.  The person who provided me with the prototype had the ampersand right next to the function name and it confused me.  I guess it's returning a constant location by reference?  Why would he want it to return it by reference?

Comment: @klamse A possible motivation is to avoid unneeded copying of `Location`.

Comment: That makes complete sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
const Location& LocationStack::getTop(void) const 
{
}
```

You can read this as "a reference to a `const Location` object"

Answer (score 1):

```
const Location &getTop(void) const;
```

The return type is always positioned to the left of the variable name (except in certain other cases). The rules for naming a function are the same for variables - they can only contain certain characters, `&` not being one of them.

The return type above actually means *reference to a `const Location` object*. `&` designates a reference to a certain type. You may have seen this operator used for obtaining the address of an object. That is just one of its various uses.

Since `getTop` is the name of the function, `&` can't apply there. You should define it like this:

```
const Location& LocationStack::getTop(void) const {

}
```

Where return type is kept the same and the name of the function is correctly specified.